# Showing only one category on wordpress homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I'm trying to display only one category on my homepage here. To do this, I know I have to edit the index.php file but I have no idea why my code isn't taking. In this case, the ID of the post category I want to display is "1"

Here's the code (my edit is the last line):

```
<div class="row">

    <!-- Contains the loop of all posts -->
    <div class="col-md-8" id="post-container">

        <!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php if (in_category('1')&& is_home()) continue; ?>
```

Any ideas?

DISCLAIMER: I am in no way fluent in php, I was just told that this should be an easy issue to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this properly you need to run a filter on your data for the homepage... the other answers and what you're doing will not work properly with pagination... if for example the last X posts aren't in the category you want to show you will get 0 results or less then ideal...

You want to run the filter in such a way..

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', 'YOUR CATEGORY ID HERE' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

This will work properly and let you still utilize proper pagination. You can find more information about filters here -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Bart

Comment: +1 for this answer. This is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<?php if (in_category(1)&& is_home()) continue; ?>`. The ID must be an integer, otherwise it will be considered a slug.

Answer (score 0):

[More info for argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

```
<?php $args = array(
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'style'              => 'list',
    'include'            => '',
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
    'show_option_none'   => __( 'No categories' ),
    'number'             => 1,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'walker'             => null
); ?>

<?php if (is_home()) { ?>
 <ul class="categories">
   <?php wp_list_categories($args); ?>
 </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of going through all the posts and filter out the post you wanted,

Try using the

query_posts( 'cat=1');

//this will alter the main loop, then you can have a lots more control, like post per page and so on

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

Comment: `query_posts` should **NEVER** be used